# Javascript - W char code for onKeyPress event not working

Tags: javascript, ascii, keypress

This works for the enter key, but does not seem to work for w. Below is my code.

```
function onKeyPress(event){
    keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){
        case 87: //w
            console.log("w");
        break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress, false);
```

Why does this not work for the W key? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the capital W, why thats not logging to console?

Comment: lowercase w has keyCode `119`

Answer (score 2):

Lowercase `w` is **119**, capital `W` is **87**.

```
function onKeyPress(event){
    keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){
        case 119: //w
            console.log("w");
            break;
        case 87: // W
            console.log('W');
            break;
    }
}
```

[ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-w-minuscule-ascii-code-119.html)

Comment: This works. However, my caps lock is not on, and shift is not held down. Why would it be registering as a capital W? EDIT:Nevermind, the above edit answers my question